# "очевидно" або "очебачно"?

Tags: вибір-слова

Чому на суспiльному теле*баченнi* вживають слово "очевидно" замість "очебачно"? Хiба ми кажемо "*виділи* очi, що купували...", або "телевиден'є"?

Comment: так, ми кажемо "виділи очі, що купували".
https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=%22%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D1%96%D0%BB%D0%B8+%D0%BE%D1%87%D1%96+%D1%89%D0%BE+%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%22
одна з причин майбутнього закриття цього питання — що ви навіть не пошукали в ґуґлі й не подивилися, чи є в українській мові здавна слово "видіти" паралельно до "бачити".

Comment: [ВИ́ДІТИ](http://sum.in.ua/s/vydity), джу, диш, недок., діал. Бачити. Розповідають люди, що виділи на власні очі [машину], і не можуть нахвалитися (Іван Франко, II, 1950, 38); Виділа я, що на нашому полі Гарне в цім році вродилося жито (Дмитро Павличко, Бистрина, 1959, 105).

Comment: ВИ́ДІТИ - це діалектне слово, або, як казала наша вчителька: "Це - русизм".

Comment: Видіти аж ніяк не "русизм", а цілком питоме слово.

Answer (score 0):

**ВИДІ́ННЯ** - зорові образи, що здаються людині реальними і сприймаються за явні, але не пов'язані з матеріальним світом.

[Видіння](https://archive.org/details/literaturoznavchat1/page/n175/mode/1up?view=theater) можуть бути також слухові, залучати інші органи чуття. Таке особливе "**бачення очима духу**" зазвичай відбувається уві сні або під час засинання, але може траплятися і наяву, в пророчому або містичному стані.

Елементи [видіння](https://uk.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%B4%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F) спостерігаються в античній літературі та середньовічному письменництві.

[**Приви́дітися, приви́дітись**](https://uk.worldwidedictionary.org/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D1%96%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8F) - ВВИЖА́ТИСЯ кому (**поставати перед очима ніби наяву**), БА́ЧИТИСЯ, МАЯ́ЧИ́ТИ, МАЯЧІ́ТИ, МА́РИТИСЯ, ПРИВИ́ДЖУВАТИСЯ, ПРИВИДЖА́ТИСЯ, ЗДАВА́ТИСЯ, рідше ПРИВИЖА́ТИСЯ, рідко УЗДРІВА́ТИСЯ, рідко ВИ́ДІТИСЯ, розм. МРІ́ТИСЯ, МЕРЕ́ЩИТИСЯ розм. рідко, ВВИ́ДЖУВАТИСЯ, МАЯ́ЧИ́ТИСЯ безос. діал. Док.: **приви́дітися, уздрі́тися, сни́тися, уявля́тися**.

Док.: **присни́тися, насни́тися, прима́ритися, приверзти́ся, наверзти́ся, примрі́ятися, примрі́тися, приви́дітися, ви́роїтися, ввижа́тися**.

Що до очей, як до органу зору, їми можна **бачити, дивитися, споглядати, спостерігати, слідкувати, пильнувати та ін**.